# PDEs for string deflection.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, integral-transforms, wave-equation

Okay, I have to find $u(x,t)$ for the string of length $L=\pi$ when $c^2=1$.

I know:
$$\text{wave equation}: \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
$$u(x,0)=\frac x{10}(\pi-x)$$
$$u_t(x,0)=0$$

Now I am fairly sure I set $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$

My textbook starts using $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=F\ddot{G}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=F''G$, I am not sure, are these(F,G) the same as $f(x)$ and $g(x)$? Why are they captilised?

Are they transformed using Laplace or Fourier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method used there is separation of variables. We suppose that we can separate $u(x,t)$ as a product of two functions $G(t)$ and $F(x)$. Then we find the derivatives in the differential equation as
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=F\ddot{G}
\\ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=F''G$$ we then substitute in the given PDE 
$$F\ddot{G}=c^2 F''G\implies \frac{\ddot G}{c^2G}=\frac{F''}{F}=\lambda $$
Now we have two ordinary differential equations
$$\ddot G-\lambda c^2 G=0\\F''-\lambda F=0$$
Now we have three cases($\lambda=0, \lambda\lt 0,\lambda\gt0$). The first case implies that $F$ is linear and this doesn't agree with the initial condition. The second case: put $\lambda=-\alpha^2$ then
$$\ddot G+\alpha^2 c^2 G=0\\F''+\alpha^2 F=0$$ These equations say that
$$G=A\cos(\alpha c t)+B\sin(\alpha c t)
\\ F=C\cos(\alpha x)+D\sin(\alpha x)$$ The second condition $\dot G(0)=0$ implies that $B=0$. Thus the general solution is
$$u(x,t)=A\cos(\alpha c t)\{C\cos(\alpha x)+D\sin(\alpha x)\}
\\ u(x,t)=\cos(\alpha c t)\{a\cos(\alpha x)+b\sin(\alpha x)\}$$
Now you can it from here.
You can see [that](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SeparationofVariables.aspx)

Comment: So above I have $F(x)\dot{G}(0)=0$ and $\frac1{10}x(\pi-x) = F(x)G(0)$? Hence I want to now find $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac1{10}x(\pi-x))$?

Comment: $F(x)\dot{G}(0)=0\implies \dot{G}(0)=0$ for general $F$

Comment: and the first condition is used later after the solution of the ODEs

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to attack the problem, since I have already subbed in $t=0$, how would I go about finding anything from that?

Comment: I think part of my confusion arises from the fact that my $f(x)$ isn't a standard $0\lt x \lt \frac{L}2$ and $\frac{L}2 \lt x \lt L$

Comment: If you could link me to a solution of a similar question, that would be greatly appreciated, I have had poor luck locating anything without a piecewise definition of $f(x)$(which I don't seem to have)

Comment: I put a link in the solution

Comment: Thank you, I will look though all this and I should be fine!

Comment: So if $\gamma\gt0$, we have solution $A+Be^{\gamma x}$, why was this ruled out? Because it doesn't meet the $L=\pi$?

Comment: Or is it because:

$A+Be^{\gamma x}=\frac{x}{10}(\pi-x)$ at $x=0$, $A+B=0\implies A=-B$

$x=\pi \implies B(-1+e^{\lambda \pi})=0\implies B=0$
$$0=\frac{x}{10}(\pi-x)$$

Comment: I am still having trouble, I am sorry. I don't know why $\lambda = -\alpha^2$ was chosen? And was $\lambda \gt 0$ discluded for the reason above?

Comment: We exclude the positive case physically or mathematically. In this case the the function $F$ will be $Ae^{\alpha x}+Be^{-\alpha x}$ which has at most one zero while $u(x,0)$ has two zeros.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand now. You were amazing!